# Type I Error for unknown population variance T-test?

Tags: statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

On the lecture I am taking, a example was given to do hypothesis test on population with unknown variance. And the solution is first **test the samples' deviation based on F-test and favor the Null hypotheis** of equal variance and perform t-test for equal variance.

But (I assume) the the null hypothesis of the followed t-test would be $$ \mathcal{H_0} : \{\mu_{diff} = 0 \mid accepting\ hypothesis\ that\ variances\ are\ equal\}$$

And then the Type I error would be the probability of :
$$
P(Type\ I\ error\mid equal\ variances) = \\P(reject\ \mathcal{H}_0\mid \mathcal{H}_0:\{\mu_{diff} = 0 \mid accepting\ hypothesis\ that\ variances\ are\ equal\})
$$

Which is not the same as the common hypothesis test which probability of Type I error given null hypothesis is true is happen to be $\alpha$ that we set.

Given the consideration of above nonsense, the should the **total probability of Type I error** of this experiment be
$$
P(Type\ I\ error) =\\ P(Type\ I\ error\mid equal\ variances)\times\ P(samples\ variances\ are\ equal)\\
+P(Type\ I\ error\mid unequal\ variances)\times\ P(samples\ variances\ are\ unequal)
$$

If correct, what are the $P(samples\ variances\ are\ equal)\ and\ P(samples\ variances\ are\ unequal)$?

Comment: Why are you testing the hypothesis that the population variances are equal? Are you doing this to see if you should use the pooled variance when performing the $t-$ test for the difference between two population means?

Comment: Dear Holder. Yes, that's is correct, to test if we should use pooled variance t-test.

Comment: So when you refer to a Type I error, are you referring to a Type I error for the hypothesis test $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_2$ versus $H_1:\mu_1 \neq \mu_2$, or are you referring to a Type I errror for the test $H_0: \sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2$ versus $H_1: \sigma_1^2 \neq \sigma_2^2$? Also, are the alternative hypotheses two tailed for both tests? Lastly, performing the hypothesis test for equal variances requires that we're sampling from populations which are normally distributed.  Do you have that information?